# How to add a second domain to an EC2 instance with Elastic & Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, domain-parking

I've got my domain `site.com` running on EC2, using Elastic IP and Route 53. I want to park `site.net` so that it resolves to the same site..

I've looked up [Migrating an Existing Domain to Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html) in the docs, but can't find mention of how to add a second domain!

I figured I'd have to create an A record, but when I do so, the record is created `site.net.site.com` .. not quite what I'm after!

I've also done searches for mixes of 'route 53', 'park domain', 'addon domain', 'second domain', but no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an entirely new zone in Route 53 (with similar records as `site.com`), not add a record to `site.com`.